# Has a "lucky loser" ever won an ATP or WTA tournament?

Tags: tennis, records, atp, wta

[This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10260/how-is-lucky-loser-decided-in-wta-tournaments) made me wonder if a "lucky loser" has ever won a big tournament (ATP, WTA etc.)? If it has happened, is there some kind of overview of all the players that did so?

Comment: Wikipedia article has a section named [Lucky losers as tennis tournament winners and finalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_loser#Lucky_losers_as_tennis_tournament_winners_and_finalists). However, the information given there seems a bit incomplete and lacking references.

Comment: Some related information can also be found here: 
[The Luck of the Loser: Tennis’ Legendary (LL)s](http://thetennisisland.com/2015/01/07/the-luck-of-the-loser-tennis-legendary-lls/),
[Best "Lucky Losers" list](http://tt.tennis-warehouse.com/showthread.php?t=426667)

Comment: [This post](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=147569&page=5) mentions 6 case where it happened in ATP events. Wikipedia claims there were seven, but does not list the names. [This article](http://tennisnews.com/exclusive.php?pID=23983) mentions 5 names.

Comment: I think that the articole you mentioned is before Ram's victory in Newport

Answer (score 4):

Those players have won an ATP tournament as a lucky loser:

- Heinz Gunthardt (Springfield 1978)
- Bill Scanlon (Maui 1978)
- Francisco Clavet ([Hilversum 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_Dutch_Open_%E2%80%93_Singles))
- Christian Miniussi (Sao Paulo 1991)
- Sergiy Stakhovsky ([Zagreb 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_PBZ_Zagreb_Indoors))
- Rajeev Ram ([Newport 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Hall_of_Fame_Tennis_Championships_%E2%80%93_Singles))
- Andrey Rublev ([Umag 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Croatia_Open_Umag_%E2%80%93_Singles))
- Leonardo Mayer ([Hamburg 2017](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/scores/current/hamburg/414/draws))
- Marco Cecchinato ([Budapest 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Gazprom_Hungarian_Open_%E2%80%93_Singles))

Answer (score 2):

Lucky losers that won WTA tournaments:<sup>1</sup>

- [Olga Danilović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olga_Danilovi%C4%87) ([Moscow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Moscow_River_Cup_%E2%80%93_Singles) 2018)

**Sources**

- Wikipedia article [Lucky loser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_loser#Lucky_losers_as_tennis_tournament_winners_and_finalists)
- [Danilovic claims first title in Moscow after all-teen tussle](http://www.wtatennis.com/news/danilovic-claims-first-title-moscow-after-all-teen-tussle) - WTA website ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180730113427/http://www.wtatennis.com/news/danilovic-claims-first-title-moscow-after-all-teen-tussle))
- [38 years later Lucky Loser win again WTA tournament](https://www.tennisforum.com/12-general-messages/1315633-38-years-later-lucky-loser-win-again-wta-tournament.html) - Tennis Forum

<sup>1</sup>Several sources claimed that actually the first lucky loser WTA winner was [Andrea Jaeger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea_Jaeger) in 1980 Las Vegas. (For example, [several revisions of the Wikipedia article on Lucky loser](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lucky_loser&oldid=850077427#Lucky_losers_as_tennis_tournament_winners_and_finalists), [another article on WTA website](http://www.wtatennis.com/news/serena-wins-stanford-ties-venus-43-titles).)